# How to use laravel cashier charge with `withMetaData` and `create`

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am new to `laravel cashier`, and I am stuck here.

For my games, users can subscribe. I have 3 subscription methods.

- Monthly
- Yearly
- One-time.

For **monthly** and **Yearly** subscriptions, I have used the below code and it works perfectly.

```php
$subscription = $user->newSubscription($subscriptionName, $plan->stripe_id)->withMetaData(['game' => $game->name])->create(null, [
    'email' => $user->email,
    'name'  => $user->name,
    ['metadata' => ['game' => $game->name]],
], $subscriptionOptions);
```

But for the **one-time** subscription, I have used the below code

```php
$subscription = $user->charge(2500, 'pm_1IpuT.....')->withMetaData(['game' => $game->name])->create(null, [
    'email' => $user->email,
    'name'  => $user->name,
    ['metadata' => ['game' => $game->name]],
], $subscriptionOptions);
```

for this, I am and getting the below error

```
Error
Call to undefined method Laravel\Cashier\Payment::withMetaData()
```

Can anyone help to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

As they mention [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#simple-charge) you pass the `metadata` as a **third** argument in the `charge` method

```
$user->charge(100, $paymentMethod, [
    'custom_option' => $value,
]);
```

so in your example, you need to edit it like this

```
$subscription = $user->charge(2500, 'pm_1IpuT.....', [
    'metadata' => [
        'game' => $game->name,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'name'  => $user->name,
    ]
]);
```

> for more additional data to pass check stripe [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create)

Comment: tnx for your quick response I have tried that already. For that, I am getting `Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException Received unknown parameters: game, email, name` error. How Can I solve this?

Comment: change it to `metadata` as the last update in the answer

Comment: The error is gone. But it is not creating a new row in the database. For `month` and `year`, it is creating.

Comment: is it working or not i can't understand you correctelly